# Swipe between UITableViews like Livescore app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am trying to expand my application that is currently in the App Store. I found an interesting way to change between two UITableViews by swiping and I want to implement something similar. I tried searching but had no luck, most of the searches ended up in swiping UITableViewCells or what Android uses "fragments"

What I want to achieve looks like this. I will show you in three different pictures taken from the livescore app. Since I can't upload images here I will give you dropbox url:

View1

[image]

View2 (starting to swipe, can see the data on the other view already)

[image]

View3 (finished swiping)

Can't post the link since im restricted to two links...

Any ideas what they are using for technique? What it is called and/or if you have a good tutorial for it would be appreciated.

Comment: Just put your tableviews into a scroll view and implement paging.

Comment: I think @Paulw11 has your answer. They might be doing it differently but I think his suggestion is probably easiest.

Comment: Or you could use iCarousel to make it easier.

Comment: any pros/cons using iCarousel to Paging?

Comment: Here are a couple of nice open source implementations of this: https://github.com/y-hryk/YSLContainerViewController https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip